# Could we install MS CRM On Premise on the new Azure IAAS

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, crm, iaas

Can we install Microsoft CRM on Windows Azure IAAS platform. Is this possible to import a Windows VM of MS CRM.

Has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal knowledge Running Microsoft CRM on Windows Azure Virtual Machines (IaaS Platform) is not a supported product yet. For technical testing/eval purpose you sure can install in on a single Virtual Machines and test it.

The link below shows a list of support Microsoft Products on Windows Azure Virtual Machines:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2721672/de